# Use admin login form then redirect back to page

Tags: django, python-2.7, redirect

Right now I have an app here:

```
htttp://localhost/main
```

Which requires a login for django's authentication. I want to use the admin login form `http://localhost/admin/login`. The problem is that by default the admin login redirects back to itself, but I want it to redirect back to `http://localhost/main`. Is there a way I can get this done?

This is my view currently

```
@login_required(login_url='/admin', redirect_field_name='main'
def main_view(request):
     return render(request, 'main_site.html')
```

By doing this, it just redirects me to the following URL:

```
http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/admin/%3Fmain%3D/main/
```

But I need it to be

```
http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/main/
```

Answer (score 0):

The Django auth app comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), including a `login` view. It would be better to use this login view rather than reusing the admin login view.

If you really want to use the admin login view, you could try changing it to:

```
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
```

Changing the `login_url` prevents the user being redirect first to `/admin/` and then to `/admin/login/`. I've removed `redirect_field_name='main'` as I do not believe it will be possible to use a custom `redirect_field_name` with the admin login view.